# Firebase Cloud Functions error_: variable is not defined

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I get this error:

```
ReferenceError: userid is not defined
  at exports.onUserNickUpdate.functions.firestore.document.onWrite (/srv/index.js:49:34)
    at cloudFunctionNewSignature (/srv/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:120:23)
    at /worker/worker.js:825:24
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)
```

When I run this function(gets triggered by write on document):

```
exports.onUserNickUpdate = functions.firestore.document('user/{userid}').onWrite((change,context) => {

    const changednick = change.after.data().nick

    return highscore_collection.doc(userid).set({
        nick: changednick
    })
})
```

Error is from this line `highscore_collection.doc(userid).set`. I don't understand this error, how come userid is not defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never defined the variable `userid`.  It doesn't get automatically created just because you declared it as a wildcard in your trigger definition.  Please read the documentation on [using wildcards in a Firestore trigger](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#wildcards-parameters).  To get its matched value, pull it out of the context provided to the function:

```
const userid = context.params.userid;
```